# WARNING: Requirement 'PyOpenGL‑3.1.5‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist

Tags: python, opengl, visual-studio-code

I am trying to install PyOpenGL that includes freeglut. I dwonloaded the .whl file [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl)

I executed the command:

```
pip install PyOpenGL-3.1.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```

And I got an error message:

```
WARNING: Requirement 'PyOpenGL‑3.1.5‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
ERROR: PyOpenGL‑3.1.5‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl is not a valid wheel filename.
```

I don't know if I have to put the .whl in a specific directory.

Comment: You have to run the command "pip install ..." in the directory where the file is saved.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! THIS WAS THE ANSWER I AM LOOKING FOR. My directory was messed up from the beggining. I first used cmd.exe to install, it worked but it doesnt change my visual studio code. So I put the ,whl files on my workspace and used the terminal to install.

Comment: I am very happy for you